# Can I share all of my Google Drive with others?

Tags: google-drive, sharing

Can I share my entire Google Drive contents with another without sharing individual folders one at a time?

Comment: If not, just create one folder that you drag all the others into, and share that one.

Answer (score 2):

No, I'm afraid you cannot. You can only share folders and/or files.

The obvious solution is to simply create a folder in the root of Google Drive and share that. Then you need only make sure you save all of your files somewhere in that folder.